# how can I get a list of AWS instance names and private IPs using aws cli filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I get a list of instance Names and private IPs. This is what I have so far:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances   --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress"   --output=text  --profile=company-lab
```

I'd like to amend that to also include the instance Name tags as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out how to do this. In case anyone else is interested, here's my solution:

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[ [Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value][0][0],PrivateIpAddress,State.Name]' --output table --profile=company-lab
```